# Akka routing messages with single running instance per id

Tags: java, scala, akka

Let say I have a series of messages that contain an id identifying a client. Messages for different clients can be processed in parallel. Messages for the same client can only be processed one at a time.

With Akka I would like to be able to route the messages to a pool of actors but meet this at most one concurrent actor per client id constraint.

What would be the best way to approach this? Am I misunderstanding any concepts behind Akka or trying to apply traditional concepts that do not fit the actor model?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can fit the actor model quite simply. As - by definition - a single actor processes its incoming messages sequentially, one simple way to go about this could be to create one actor per client.

Take this simple example, where you use one single actor as a router, and one worker per existing client.

```
  class Boss extends Actor {

    override def receive: Receive = jobHandler(Map.empty[ClientId, ActorRef])

    def jobHandler(workers: Map[ClientId, ActorRef]): Receive = {

      case j@Job(id, ...) if workers contains id => 
        workers(id) ! j

      case j@Job(id, ...) =>
        val worker = context.actorOf(Props[Worker])
        worker ! j
        context.become(jobHandler(workers + (id -> worker)))
    }
  }

  class Worker extends Actor {
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case Job(...) => doStuff(...)
    }
  }
```

Keep in mind actors are very lightweight so this holds even if you need to keep track of a lot of them.

Comment: Or if you are looking to build a clustered system, look into Cluster Sharding http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-sharding.html#cluster-sharding-scala